# discord.js I keep getting what the bot says instead of user's message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I keep getting : "What is your suggestion" in DMs in the bot instead of the answer to the question the user gives

```js
else if(msg.content === 'suggest')
          {
            msg.delete();
            msg.reply('What is your suggestion?');
            msg.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == msg.author.id,
            {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
                    var answer = msg.content;
                    bot.users.get('349463140229971989').send(answer.toLowerCase());
                  })
            //bot.users.get('349463140229971989').send(msg.content);
          }
```

I've also tried this :

```js
else if(msg.content.startsWith('suggest '))
              {
                var user = msg.mentions.users.first();
                var answer = msg.content;
                bot.users.get('349463140229971989').send(answer.toLowerCase() + " from : " + msg.author);
                msg.delete();
                msg.reply('Your suggestion has been forwarded');
              }
```

I get "*your suggestion has been forwarded*"
, and it sends me the bot's reply and not my message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you aren't taking the collected messages content but rather the command msg here:

```js
var answer = msg.content;
```

change it to:

```js
var answer = collection.first().content;
```

But what if the user doesn't send a message? Well you would probably want to send a message back that time is up, to do so you need to add time as one of the errors and add a catch statement:

```js
else if(msg.content === 'suggest') {
    msg.delete();
    msg.reply('What is your suggestion?');
    
    const filter = m => m.author.id == msg.author.id;
    const options = {max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"]};

    msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
        .then(collected => {
            const answer = collected.first().content;
            bot.users.get('349463140229971989').send(answer.toLowerCase());
            msg.reply("Suggestion forwarded");
        })
        .catch(err => msg.reply("Suggestion canceled"));
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked but also I just changed this like a week ago to just slice the message and use that.